# IntelliJ can't find Scala/SBT GetClassifiersModule

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Brand new to SBT here, which may very well be the culprit. I'm trying to get IntelliJ Community 2017.2 to import [a simple Scala/SBT project](https://github.com/bitbythecron/scala-idea-sbt-troubleshooting) of mine.

When you clone that repo you can (if you want) run `sbt compile` and/or `sbt run` to verify that the dinky little `Driver.scala` source compiles and runs as expected.

But when I try importing it into IntelliJ:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Oops! That is a huge stacktrace but ends with:

```
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/internal/librarymanagement/GetClassifiersModule
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

**Any idea what is going on here? Anything in my project (see the GH repo) that jumps out?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12336, this problem was fixed in 2017.3, please try 2017.3 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/